# Working with directories/files different in UWP and Console?

Tags: c#, directory, win-universal-app

Simple question :-)

Can anyone explain me following:
When I perform this code in console app (VS2015, C#, without the Async/Task.Run), it works and the directory is found.

However, when I run the same code with the same directory as variable in a Universal Windows Platform, the directory isn't found anymore. (So the script returns: is not a valid file or directory)

Here is the code:

```
GetFilesList("E:\\Programmeren\\jpegs");

private async void GetFilesList(String path)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
     {
         Task.Yield();
         if (File.Exists(path))
         {
            // This path is a file
            ProcessFile(path);
         }
         else if (Directory.Exists(path))
         {
            // This path is a directory
            ProcessDirectory(path);
         }
         else
         {
             Debug.WriteLine("{0} is not a valid file or directory.", path);
         }

     });
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In UWP, you only have access to your app's folder (installation folder, local folder and roaming folder of the app), public folder, video, photo and document folder and a limited number of other folders.

You can request access for the rest using `FilePicker` and `FutureAccesList` api.

Comment: Thank you! Simple question, simple answer :-) That was indeed the solution!